# setNoEmbed is returning error like "Call to a member function getDOM()" in Youtube API v2

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using Gdata youtube Library in zend (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html)

I am able to update setVideoTitle, setVideoDescription, SetVideoTags and setVideoCategory.But when I tried to update "setNoEmbed" it is throwing error like "Call to a member function getDOM()"

And here's my code:

```
 $myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();
 $myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle($mediaTitle);
 $myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription($mediaDescription);
 $myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory($category);
 $myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags($tags); 
 $myVideoEntry->setNoEmbed(true);
```